# Java database username and password

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am trying to become familiar with java derby database creation. As my first attempt I am trying to make a simple program that pulls some info from the database and spits it out. I feel like I am so close, but am getting this rejection:

**SQL Error:  java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection    authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Userid or password invalid.**

I made the sample derby database and it includes this code.

```
`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
          data, "app", "APP");
          Statement st = conn.createStatement())   {`
```

I got the "app" and "APP" username and password from the book I read called "Sam's Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days".

Any help will be greatly appreciated and will allow me to work on a lot of interesting new projects I have planned! Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's more than likely not the username/password.  That was just what they used in the example.  You will have to get the username and password from the database you set up or the DBA of your company's employ if this is for work.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the password from "APP" to "app" and give it a try.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243829